# Symfony2 - backup mysql database into file

Tags: mysql, symfony, phpmyadmin

Is there somewhere bundle for making backup of mysql database into file like phpmyadmin? I don't have access to shell at all.

Comment: As I said - I don;t have access to shell and any command like this.

Comment: just run `mysqldump` **by php**. Use `exec()`

Comment: In an environment of my project this tool is not available. I know `exec()` and `mysqldump`.

Comment: why don't you change the requirements for your project instead? Do you have `php of a particular version` in your requirements list? So, add a `mysqldump availability` as well. Using tools is a good thing, reinventing square wheels - isn't

Comment: what's wrong with phpmyadmin? You can try http://adminer.sourceforge.net it's only file only and less hassle to setup...

Answer (score 1):

I'm using **CloudBackupBundle** for backup DB and files. 
This bundle helps you to backup your databases and upload it to the cloud with only one Symfony2 command.

With this bundle, you can create Cron command to create and upload backup to cloud storage.

[GitHub repository.](https://github.com/dizda/CloudBackupBundle)